# MongoDB 3.4.8 Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB version 3.4.8 and performing aggregation to fetch data from two collections but I get this error-

```
Assert: command failed: {
"errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$lookup'",
"code" : 16436,
"ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
```

My collections are-

```
favourite_cameras is {
"_id" : ObjectId("59b3846adacd8a1afd8696a1"),
"Member_ID" : 712,
"MemberToken" : "Ns9fAEHYRkVgAZJb4UD3gbLWWIJiEoYn",
"Favourite_Camera_ID" : "1003",
"lastUpdated" : "2017-09-09 11:34:26"
}
```

and

```
traffic_images - {
"_id" : ObjectId("59b36caf32586b76d2a68160"),
"CameraID" : "1003",
"CameraName" : "ACE",
"lastUpdated" : "2017-09-09 09:53:11"
}
```

My query is-

```
db.favourite_cameras.aggregate([{
  $lookup:
    {
      from: "traffic_images",
      localField: "Favourite_Camera_ID",
      foreignField: "CameraID",
      as: "favs"
    }
}])
```

Comment: Log into the mongo shell and type `db.version()`. What will be returned will show you the server is not 3.4.8. If you recently upgraded, you likely need to stop and restart the `mongod` service if an earlier version was still running when you processed the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I recently upgraded the version to 3.4.8 but db.version() shows 3.0.15. Restarting worked.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I have been on 3.4.1 for ages. I have logged into the shell and 'db.version()' returns 3.4.1. I am stuck here too

Comment: can you share your query and collection structures here? You might me missing something or going wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

After Upgrading Mongo Shell Version, you have to set feature compatibility also.

To upgrade feature compatibility:

```
use admin;
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } );
```

Hope it helps.